# How do I output the geojon points on google maps using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get an understanding javascript and json objects on a whole. Forgive my beginner lingo but I have these five json objects(which are the result of a database query) I am trying to display these five coordinates onto the map.  I spent the last three hours searching the internet to find some relevant info on googlemaps. That was a failure, now i am here on SO.  I would like to know how do i go about outputting the coordinates onto a google map. Below is my code but for some reason my map doesn't load.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script>


        var json = {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                [40.7666969299316, -73.9906158447266],
                [40.6885147094727, -73.9647598266602],
                [40.7145042419434, -74.0056304931641],
                [40.704719543457, -74.0092620849609],
                [40.7271041870117, -74.0029678344727]
            ]
        }

        var map;


             function initialize() {
           var mapOptions = {
               zoom: 12,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.730610, -73.935242),
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                   mapOptions);


           var cods = json.coordinates;
           for (i = 0; i < cods.length; i++) {

               latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cods[i][1], cods[i][0]);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: latlng,
                   map: map,
                   title: 'test'
               });

           }
       }
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
      </head>
    <body>
  <div> <!-- ommiting this div will show the map -->
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**UPDATE:**

So scaisEdge  greatly helped me get my map to display. so the map is generated, but i am unable to load the markers from the json object onto the map. I get  **uncaught Eb ... You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page** Can someone help me to show the markers from the json object onto google maps?

**ALSO**  [here](http://w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA4XD8LD7ND9) is a link to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a marker for each lat,lng  you should place the marker creation inside the loop   and this inside tye function initilize()

```
  var json = {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            [40.7666969299316, -73.9906158447266],
            [40.6885147094727, -73.9647598266602],
            [40.7145042419434, -74.0056304931641],
            [40.704719543457, -74.0092620849609],
            [40.7271041870117, -74.0029678344727]
        ]
    }

    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.730610, -73.935242),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);




      var cods = json.coordinates;
      for (i=0; i<cods.length; i++){

        latlng =  new google.maps.LatLng( cods[i][1], cods[i][0]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latlng,
           map: map,
          title: 'test'
        });

     }
```

Comment: There is at least one typo in your code (from the original post). JavaScript is case sensitive, `latlng` is different from `latLng`. `data.title` is not defined.

Comment: Hey @scaisEdge Thanks for the response. The map is generated but the markers don't populate. Any idea why?

Comment: I have update the answer  wrong $json  and  entry[1] + entry[0] instead of json and  entry[1], entry[0]

Comment: The error message is Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(…)

Comment: I still get Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(…).

Comment: answer  updated  you have a data.title in title attribute of marker ... changed  in a static text ..

Comment: Awh man, this is annoying, Now i get *uncaught Eb ... You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page*

Comment: I see only one script for google maps  .. check for your code .. in the code you provided  this error is not evaluable  . so...

Comment: Here is the link to my code. http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA4XD8LD7ND9

Comment: looking to you code .. should work but  you get an error that i don't understand  .. so i can help  in this case ..

Comment: Okay i shall update my question and give you the necessary credit.

Comment: @MichealC.   many thanks .. i suggest you of post a new question strictly  related  to your last probleme  .. with a specific title  .. and the correct code  .. so all the SO comunity can help for your actual problem ..